# React UseContext with useReducer re-renders the whole app even after splitting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I am struggling to prevent my whole app getting re-rendered.I have even tried to split the context and memoize components but nothing helps me.
I have already read [Use context Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15156) this thread and a lot of other articles describing the right implementation but with no result.
I am using websockets to retrieve bitcoin value every second and it causes the whole app re-render on every second.

This is the `App.tsx`

```
<AppProvider>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <AppRoot isBusy={!ready || !isConnected} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ThemeProvider>
</AppProvider>
```

This is the main context

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, Dispatch } from 'react';

import { BTCReducerActions, BTCData, BTCPayload, btcReducer } from '../reducers/btc';
import { CommonReducerActions, CommonData, CommonPayload, commonReducer } from '../reducers/common';
import { UserReducerActions, UserData, UserPayload, userReducer } from '../reducers/user';

interface InitialStateType {
  user: UserData;
  btc: BTCData;
  common: CommonData;
}

const initialState: InitialStateType = {
  btc: {} as BTCData,
  common: {},
  user: {} as UserData,
};

export type ActionType = (
  BTCReducerActions |
  CommonReducerActions |
  UserReducerActions |
);
type MainReducer = (state: InitialStateType, action: ActionType) => InitialStateType;

const AppContext = createContext<{
  state: InitialStateType;
  dispatch: Dispatch<ActionType>;
}>({
  state: initialState,
  dispatch: () => null,
});

const mainReducer: MainReducer = ({ btc, common, user}, action) => ({
  btc: btcReducer<BTCPayload>(btc, action as BTCReducerActions),
  user: userReducer<UserPayload>(user, action as UserReducerActions),
  common: commonReducer<CommonPayload>(common, action as CommonReducerActions),
});

const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppProvider, AppContext };
```

And this is the `root.tsx`

```
export const AppRoot = memo(({ isBusy }: Record<'isBusy', boolean>) => {
  const {
    dispatch,
    state: {
      common: { isMobile, soundSettings: { state, volume } },
      user: { token },
    },
  } = useContext(AppContext);

  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isBusy) {
      SocketManager.socketEmitter('query', {
        header: { action: 'main::getInitialData' },
      }, ({ token, user: { id } }) => dispatch({ type: UserActionTypes.UpdateUserData, payload: { token, id } }));
    }
  }, [isBusy]);

  return (
    <AppRootStyled className="fb horizontal">
        <Content>
          <AppHeader />
          <div className="fb main-content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact strict path={GAME_SCREEN} component={Roulette} />
              <Route exact strict path={STATISTICS_SCREEN} component={Activity} />
              <Route exact strict path={BET_HISTORY_SCREEN} render={props => <BetHistory roundHistory={roundHistory} {...props} />} />
              <Route exact strict path={USER_BETS_SCREEN} component={MyBets} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Content>
        {location.pathname !== GAME_SCREEN && (
          <div className="go-home">
            <div className="fb horizontal aCenter jCenter">
              <Icon name="round-back-circled" onClick={() => history.push(GAME_SCREEN)} />
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </AppRootStyled>
  );
});
```

Somewhere in the app I am using socket to get the btc data

```
useEffect(() => {
    SocketManager.connectChannel('main::BTCData', (data) => {
      dispatch({ type: BTCActionTypes.SetBTCData, payload: data });
    });
  }, []);
```

I have already tried to create a separate context by splitting the main state so the btc data has its own slice of the state, but again the Route components re-render every second.Also other components that use the context are re-rendering every second.
This is the context splitting implementation

```
const AppContext = {/ ** \}

const BtcContext = createContext<{btc: BTCData}>({ btc: {} as BTCData });

const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <BtcContext.Provider value={{btc}}>
        {children}
      </BtcContext.Provider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I know I am doing something wrong.I am using context as a state management service for the first time.Before I was using only redux and haven't faced this kind of problem.
I am already on it a few days and I need to solve the problem until tomorrow morning.
I have a lot of tables and other heavy components that shouldn't re-render so often.

**UPDATED**

I have tried this 2 options.
OPTION 1

```
<AppProvider>
  <BtcProvider>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <AppRoot isBusy={!ready || !isConnected} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </BtcProvider>
</AppProvider>


const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [{ btc, ...mainStateData }, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  const mainState = useMemo(() => ({
    state: mainStateData,
    dispatch,
  }), [mainStateData]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={mainState}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const BtcProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [{ btc }, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  const btcData = useMemo(() => ({
    btc,
    dispatch,
  }), [btc]);

  return (
    <BtcContext.Provider value={btcData}>
      {children}
    </BtcContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppProvider, BtcProvider, AppContext, BtcContext };
```

And OPTION 2

```
const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [{ btc, ...mainStateData }, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  const mainState = useMemo(() => ({
    state: mainStateData,
    dispatch,
  }), [mainStateData]);

  const btcData = useMemo(() => ({
    btc,
    dispatch,
  }), [btc]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={mainState}>
      <BtcContext.Provider value={btcData}>
        {children}
      </BtcContext.Provider>

    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};


 <AppProvider>
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <GlobalStyles />
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <AppRoot isBusy={!ready || !isConnected} />
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ThemeProvider>
```

The result is the same.The case is that the btc data is being changed every second and I need it to provide a lot of components, but to re-render only the components where I consume the data.

Comment: Components will rerender when state or props update, or their parent component rerenders. This is how React works. If you update the state in a Context, it and its subtree will rerender. Use the `memo` HOC to hint to React that a child component may not need to rerender.

Answer (score 1):

```
<AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
```

Every time AppProvider renders, this code creates a new object `{ state, dispatch }`. It may have the same contents as the previous object, but it's a different object, so react is forced to rerender any component that consumes this context. Similarly, you're making a brand new object for the BtcContext.Provider.

When providing an object, you need to make sure to memoize that object so it only changes when necessary:

```
const AppProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(mainReducer, initialState);

  const appValue = useMemo(() => {
    return { state, dispatch };
  }, [state]);

  const btcValue = useMemo(() => {
    return { btc };
  }, [btc]);

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appValue}>
      <BtcContext.Provider value={btcValue}>
        {children}
      </BtcContext.Provider>
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: It didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: See the updated version.